# Using the Java 8 Streams API, can sorted() be relied upon when calling Collectors.toSet()?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

This is the implementation of the `java.util.stream.Collectors` class's `toSet()` method:

```
public static <T>
Collector<T, ?, Set<T>> toSet() {
    return new CollectorImpl<>((Supplier<Set<T>>) HashSet::new, Set::add,
                               (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; },
                               CH_UNORDERED_ID);
}
```

As we can see, it uses a `HashSet` and calls `add`. From the `HashSet` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), "It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time."

In the following code, a `List` of `String` is streamed, sorted and collected into a `Set`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> strings = Arrays.asList("c", "a", "b")
            .stream()
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    System.out.println(strings.getClass());
    System.out.println(strings);
}
```

This provides the output:

`class java.util.HashSet`

`[a, b, c]`

The output is sorted. What I think is happening here is that although the contract provided by the `HashSet` documentation specifies that ordering is not something it provides, the implementation happens to add in order. I suppose this could change in future versions / vary between JVMs and that a wiser approach would be to do something like `Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new)`.

Can `sorted()` be relied upon when calling `Collectors.toSet()`?

Additionally, what exactly does "it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time" mean? (I suppose `add`, `remove`, the resizing of the underlying array?)

Comment: "Can sorted() be relied upon when calling Collectors.toSet()?" No. [For example](https://ideone.com/NPVQT8).

Comment: If maintaining any order throughout different JVM instances (and/or also different JVM release cycles) is needed, one must use `LinkedHashSet` or similar classes which ensure a **deterministic** order. Reasons are given in the answers already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is no. Once you added the items into a Set you cannot rely on any order. From JDK sourcecode (HashSet.java):

```
/**
 * Returns an iterator over the elements in this set.  The elements
 * are returned in no particular order.
 *
 * @return an Iterator over the elements in this set
 * @see ConcurrentModificationException
 */
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return map.keySet().iterator();
}
```

Now, in previous versions of the JDK even though an order wasn't guaranteed, you'd usually get the items in <s>the same order of insertion (unless the class of the objects implements `hashCode()` and then you'll get the order that is dictated by `hashCode()`).</s> either the order of creation of the objects or the order of invocation of `hashCode()` on the objects. As @Holgar mentions in the comments below, in HotSpot it's the latter. And you can't even count on that since there are exceptions to this as well since the sequential number is not the only ingredient in the hashCode generator.

I recently heard a talk from [Stuart Marks](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/collections-refueled) (the guy who's responsible for a re-write of a major part of Collections in Java 9) and he said that they've added randomization to the iteration order of Sets (created by new set-factories) in Java 9. If you want to hear the session, the part that he talk about sets start [here](https://youtu.be/q6zF3vf114M?t=43m6s) - good talk, highly recommended by the way!.

So even if you used to count on iteration order of Sets, once you move to Java 9 you should stop doing so.

All that said, if you need order you should consider using a [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html),
 [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) or [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)

Comment: The randomization Stuart talked about in *JavaOne 16* only applies for the `JEP 269` collections, that are the ones returned by the new factories `Map.of(...)` etc. and not for `HashSet` or `HashMap` which remain unchanged. However you are correct, no one should **rely** on the current behavior. It already changed between some JDK release cycles and since Java 8 it also can rarely change while using it (when a collision threshold is reached it reorganizes itself by using balanced trees).

Comment: @Zabuza you're correct, the randomization was added only to the new factories (for now).

Comment: `SortedSet`s do not retain insertion order though, only `LinkedHashSet` does.

Comment: @the8472 when you're using a data-structure that maintains items sorted it's almost never done by insertion order: it defaults to natural ordering but usually you can provide a comparator that maintains the required order.

Comment: OP asked about maintaining the order produced by a stream pipeline, this is not necessarily achievable by sorting. e.g. if you produce a monotonous series (e.g. by sorting) and then add noise then this transform is not invertible and thus you cannot derive a comparator that could yield the same order in a sorted set.

Comment: “*you'd usually get the items in the same order of insertion*”—no, you do *not* get the order of insertion. It may appear to be in *sorted* order for some small sets, due to the way their element’s hash code is implemented but that is *not* the insertion order. Which is easy to verify by removing `sorted()` from the stream operation. The result order will still be `a,b,c`, not reflecting the insertion order.

Comment: @Holger you're right in cases where the class of objects in the stream override hashCode(). Try to use objects of class that doesn't implement it and you'll get the insertion order (at least for smaller sets). Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @alfasin: if you see that, it’s because the identity hashcode has been generated from either, a timer or a sequential number generator. Which implies that the order is either, the object’s instantiation order or their first `hashCode` invocation’s order (in case of HotSpot: the latter). In either case, it’s not necessarily the insertion order, e.g. insert them into one `HashSet`, then insert them into another `HashSet` in a different order and the second set will not reflect their insertion order…And there are outliers almost every time, as the sequential number is not the only hash ingredient

Comment: @Holger just tried it and you're right: it looks like it's ordered by time of the first invocation of hashCode(), answer corrected - thanks!

Answer (score 8):

To answer that question, you have to know a bit about how `HashSet` is implemented. As the name suggests, a `HashSet` is implemented using a **hash table**. Basically, a hash table is an array that is indexed by element hashes. A hash function (in Java, an object's hash is calculated by `object.hashCode()`) is basically a function that meets a few criteria:

- it is (relatively) quick to compute for a given element
- two objects that `.equals()` each other have identical hashes
- there is a low probability that different items have the same hash

So, when you meed a `HashSet` that is "sorted" (which is understood as "the iterator preserves the natural order of elements"), this is due to a couple of coincidences:

- the natural order of elements respects the natural order of their `hashCode`s
- the hash table is small enough not to have collisions (two elements with the same hash code)

If you look into the `String` class `hashCode()` method, you will see that for one-letter strings, the hash code corresponds to the Unicode index (codepoint) of the letter - so in this specific case, as long as the hash table is small enough, the elements will be sorted. However, this is a huge coincidence and

- will not hold for any other sort order
- will not hold for classes whose hashCodes do not follow their natural ordering
- will not hold hashtables with collisions

and moreover, this has nothing to do with the fact that `sorted()` was called on the stream - it's simply due to the way `hashCode()` is implemented and therefore the ordering of the hash table. Therefore, the simple answer to the question is "no".

Comment: You are right in saying that it is a pure coincidence that the result order appears to match the sorted order, but it’s also worth mentioning (explicitly), that this has nothing to do with the insertion order, i.e. that it is irrelevant whether there is a `sorted()` in the stream chain or not. By the way, for “one-letter strings”, the hash code matches their *Unicode Codepoint*, which happens to be the ASCII index only for “one-ASCII-letter strings”.